# RecyclerView.ListAdapter crashes when changing data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, listadapter, androidx

I decided to play around with the new **RecyclerView.ListAdapter** and try out if this can be used in production.

My plan was to display a placeholder (skeleton) item while the listitems are loaded and then switch to the normal itemlist once the client receives the data. The way I handle this in the **adapter** is that I pass a 'null' to *submitList()* (that way I know the data is not loaded yet).

The first part of this works very well, the **ListAdapter** starts up and displays the skeleton item, but once the 'real' list is loaded the app crashes. The reason for the crash is that the **adapter** goes directly to *onBindViewHolder()* without calling *onCreateViewHolder()* first and because of that tries to bind data to fields of the normal item that do not exist in the skeleton item.

So far I have not been able to find out why it skips the *onCreateViewHolder()* part for the first item and goes directly into binding. I checked if there maybe was some problem with the **diffUtils**, but the two items (the skeleton item and the 'real' item) are clearly different. 
(A short side note here: for some reason the breakpoints in the two **diffUtils** function never trigger at all .. I am not sure if this is also part of the problem or if this is just an **Android Studio** problem.)

The main classes that are of importance:

The ListAdapter

```
class VIPSimilarAdsAdapter(context: Context, presenterInterface: BaseVIPContract.MVPAdapterPresenter) : ListAdapter<Ad, AdViewHolderFactory.AdBaseViewHolder>(SimilarAdsDiffCallback()) {

    private val presenterInterface: WeakReference<BaseVIPContract.MVPAdapterPresenter> = WeakReference(presenterInterface)
    private var showLoadingInidicator = true

    override fun submitList(list: List<Ad>?) {
        showLoadingInidicator = list == null
        super.submitList(list)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return when (showLoadingInidicator) {
            true -> 1
            else -> super.getItemCount()
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(@NonNull holder: AdViewHolderFactory.AdBaseViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (!showLoadingInidicator) {
            getItem(position)?.let { safeAd ->
                CommonViewBinder.bindCommonFields(holder as AdViewHolderFactory.AdViewHolder, safeAd)
                AdViewBinder.bindAdFields(holder, safeAd)
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    presenterInterface.get()?.onUserEventSimilarAdClicked(safeAd, position)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AdViewHolderFactory.AdBaseViewHolder {
        return (when (showLoadingInidicator) {
            true -> AdViewHolderFactory.SkeletonViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item_skeleton, parent, false), ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_SKELETON)
            else -> AdViewHolderFactory.AdViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item_ad_basic, parent, false))
        })
    }
}
```

The DiffUtil Callback

```
class SimilarAdsDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Ad>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Ad, newItem: Ad): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Ad, newItem: Ad): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }
}
```

The **adapter** is simply called with

```
adAdapterSimilarAds.submitList(null)
```

at the start of the activity and later with

```
adAdapterSimilarAds.submitList(list)
```

once we have loaded the data.

Hope anybody has run into this problem before and can help me...

---

Edit:
here is the stacktrace of the crash

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{4e5bcfd position=6 id=-1, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{3d89e2f VFED..... ......ID 0,1953-1080,2289 #7f090302 app:id/similar_ads_after_pos_1}, adapter:ebk.vip.similar_ads.VIPSimilarAdsAdapter@ac7dc3c, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager@e9b3dc5, context:ebk.vip.vip_core.VIPActivity@ecfbcc3
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5715)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5898)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:557)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3875)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3330)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1502)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:556)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: I am talking about the ListAdapter in `androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter`, not the old one...

Comment: I mean please includes the **FULL**  message in you question.

Comment: I had similar issue, maybe there some bug with getItemCount() method. When I remove this method it works but when I override this method it crashes with error message: IndexOutOfBoundsException...

Comment: @ErcanDuman This was my problem. I removed this and everything started to work well again. I believe it is because the `ListAdapter` is maintaining its own list and if you should update your own list and then use your list as the source of the `itemsCount`, it might cause some inconsistencies which then causes the error.